# displaying element only for part of the users

Tags: asp.net

I want to show elements only to x% of the visitors to my page.
Considering low traffic  - is Random out of x% is enough in your opinion? or is it good only for high taffic?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like [A/B testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) or [multivariate testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_testing) which you can do with [Google website optimizer](http://www.Google.com/WebsiteOptimizer) or a asp.net specific library like [fairlycertain](http://www.fairtutor.com/fairlycertain/)

Just using a random number wouldn't be a good solution in any case, low or high traffic the distribution of numbers could very well not be even at all.